# A most distinguished guest

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does one mean by a ***most distinguished guest***? I'm confused about the word distinguished. I'd guess that it's a synonym to famous or important. Is that right?

Comment: Stella - for future questions about the meaning of a word or phrase, simply include a definition from a [dictionary](http://www.onelook.com/?w=distinguished&ls=a) where you looked up the word. That way, people will know that you've looked the word up, and have a better idea of how to help clarify your confusion. If you don't include that definition, the natural reaction is, "Why can't you get this definition from a dictionary?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are close.
"Distinguished" means different in a good way. A "most distinguished guest" means a guest who is very different from other guests (at the party or gathering) in a *good* way.

As an example, in a gathering of scientists, a *Nobel* prize awardee will be considered a most **distinguished** guest.

This word is used in many contexts to separate super achievers even from successful people. In a gathering of successful athletes, an Olympic gold medalist would be considered "distinguished".

Hope this helps!